# Inconsistent overflow check behavior for different types

Tags: c#, int, double, decimal, long-integer

I have this interesting piece of code:

```
private static int ConvertToInt(dynamic value)
{
    unchecked
    {
        return (int)value;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(ConvertToInt(long.MaxValue));
Console.WriteLine(ConvertToInt(double.MaxValue));
Console.WriteLine(ConvertToInt(decimal.MaxValue));
```

This outputs:

```
-1
-2147483648
System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.
```

I find this a bit strange. Why converting from `decimal` to `int` raises `OverflowException` even when I've explicitly specified `unchecked`?

**EDIT**: Interesting. [MSDN page on checked/unchecked context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/khy08726.aspx) says the following operations are affected by the overflow checking:

> Explicit numeric conversions between **integral** types.

The keyword here is **intergal**. Let's see [what types are considered intergal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3b86w.aspx):

> sbyte byte char short ushort int uint long ulong

So it makes sense that `decimal` behaves differently than `int`, but what's up with `double`?

Comment: decimal is different to other floating number objects concerning the accuracy and storing of binary numbers. It is explained in detail [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-net).

Comment: `unchecked` does not affect decimal and double at all. This is standard behavior. Also, none of this relies on dynamic. I would suggest removing it for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

First note, that:

1. `unchecked` does not affect decimal and double at all
2. none of this relies on dynamic

> what's up with double

Quoting from the C# spec:

> • For a conversion from float or double to an integral type, the processing depends on the overflow checking context (§7.6.12) in which the conversion takes place:
>
> o In an unchecked context, the conversion always succeeds, and proceeds as follows.
>
> • If the value of the operand is NaN or infinite, the result of the conversion is an unspecified value of the destination type.
>
> • Otherwise, the source operand is rounded towards zero to the nearest integral value. If this integral value is within the range of the destination type then this value is the result of the conversion.
>
> • **Otherwise, the result of the conversion is an unspecified value of the destination type.**

So the result is unspecified.

Decimal case:

> • For a conversion from decimal to an integral type, the source value is rounded towards zero to the nearest integral value, and this integral value becomes the result of the conversion. If the resulting integral value is outside the range of the destination type, a System.OverflowException is thrown.

Which is observed here.

The question is interesting and valid but if you have to ask it it's a case of a code smell. Don't rely on weird conversions except under special circumstances. All three conversions that are mentioned in the question should not occur in real-world code and further I would advise compiling `checked` except if there is a reason not to. Often, most time is spent not in application code but in other code (e.g. libraries or calls to backend systems). The performance loss of `checked` is not noticeable in those situations.